# Hazelcast: How to get Map Entry hit count on near cache?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We ae using hazelcast enterprise edition and have a requirement to get the number of hits for an entry in a map in hazelcast. We have near cache enabled for the map. We were thinking of using the entryview object to get the number of hits for this set of keys but because of near cache the number of hits are updated in near cache but not on the hazelcast server.Is there a way to get the information of number of hits for a map entry at the client side?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are an enterprise user, I suggest you use official Hazelcast support channel for your queries.

To answer your question quickly, here is the excerpt from documentation:

> If you are using Near Cache, you should take into account that your
>   hits to the keys in the Near Cache are not reflected as hits to the
>   original keys on the primary members. This has for example an impact
>   on IMap’s maximum idle seconds or time-to-live seconds expiration.
>   Therefore, even though there is a hit on a key in Near Cache, your
>   original key on the primary member may expire.

Here is the documentation: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.5/manual/html-single/index.html#near-cache